# Dice probability, Heaven or Hell

Tags: probability, dice

You're at the gate of Heaven and St. Peter asks you to play Dice with him. If you roll a 5 or 6, he'll let you into Heaven. However, if you roll a 2,3 or 4, you'll be sent to hell. If you roll a 1, he will let you re-roll. What is the chance of you entering Heaven?

Comment: It would be useful if you could tell us what you have tried, and where you have got stuck.

Answer (score 3):

I'm gonna play the devil here an give you a torturous hint.

You could avoid me if

1. You roll a 5 or 6 in the first roll, with chance $p_1 = 2/6$.
2. Or land a reroll on the first and then get a 5 or 6 on the second roll, with chance
   $$p_2 = \frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{2}{6}.$$
3. Or you land a reroll twice and then 5 or 6 with chance what?

Can you take it from here?

Bwahaha!

Answer (score 1):

We can ignore occurrence of `1` as they just reset the gamble.   So of the results that matter $3$ are bad and $2$ are good.

---

Then there's the theological question on whether Saint Peter would actually allow you to gamble on salvation or damnation with such odds, or whether perchance it is either a test or a trick?